# How to persist build directory in workspace while using docker-container as a jenkins build agent?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-docker

I am using [docker containers](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-plugin/) as Jenkins build agents. All build agents, jenkins master node are docker containers running on same host. (no different vms)

Following is the Docker Agent template I am using to build an angular app.

[image: docker-1]

[image: docker-2]

1. These are Docker Agents with sshds. Public keys are injected using env variables.
2. The build Agent docker image has npm and angular-cli installed.

Jenkins File is as follows. I can not change Jenkins file. So the above build agent has been labeled as node in jenkinsfile.

```
pipeline {


agent {
    node {
      label 'ng6'
    }

  }
  stages {
    stage('build && SonarQube analysis') {
      steps {
        withSonarQubeEnv('XX SonarQube') {
          sh '''
             npm install
             ts-node git.version.ts
             ng build --prod
             (cd dist ; tar -czf ../xx-ng.tar.gz.)
           '''
         }
      archiveArtifacts(artifacts: 'xx-ng.tar.gz', fingerprint: true)
    }
}
```

4. Build runs successfully. I am able to get artifacts

**What I am doing**
I will mount .npm and node_modules in the docker template configuration. (-v)

**What I want**

Faster build. I want to persist this workspace directory using docker volume mount option

```
/home/jenkins/workspace/xx-ng_master-ZWS24TQFDFQRGZ3QMEVULORQISDY3BPEWLM7KFGJ42I33NOQFULA
```

So that node_modules should be persistent and build will be faster. How can I get that directory path and put it in the docker agent template?

```
<Path_to_workspace>/<Path_build>
```

Comment: Have you tried mounting as volume build directory? Other possibility is create a named volume.

Comment: Question is how can I configure those volumes in cloud agent template provided in screenshots. will $BUILD_ID and $JOB_NAME work there?